# Maui iOS page swipe behavior

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui

Migrating from Xamarin.Forms to Maui, had this iOS renderer:

```
public class BaseCoreRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        if (ViewController?.NavigationController?.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = null;
        ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.ShouldBegin = OnShouldBegin;
    }

    private bool OnShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        if (NavigationController?.ViewControllers?.Length == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (Element is Page page && page.BindingContext is ViewModelBase viewModelBase)
        {
            return viewModelBase.ShouldNavigateBack();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to reuse as is (Compatibility) in Maui, app crashes.

Tried to rewrite as handler, inherit PageHandler and place content

in ConnectHandler override, NavigationController (in code above) is always null.

I am trying to connect each page's "can swipe back" behavior to its viewmodel's ShouldNavigateBack,

without creating my own Page type, or placing OnAppearing in every page.

Can you help implement this in Maui?

Is there and existing method under Maui to reach native

InteractivePopGestureRecognizer, or was its use deprecated in Maui?

Comment: You write that the app crashes, what exception do you get in the console or stack trace?

Comment: I did not mention the crash details because I tested registering the old renderer without any code in it and still crashed, meaning it was probably not meant to be used that way. Tried both registering as renderer and as a handler. The handler led to type mismatch runtime exception, while the renderer led to native runtime exception without a managed stack to inspect.

Comment: And how did you create and register the handler? You're only showing code for half of the story. If the renderer worked, but the handler doesn't, then you should show what you're actually doing that leads to the crash.

Comment: @Julian if you have actual helpful comment about how to override the swipe It would be most appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you're actually doing, first. A question like this should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which will make it easier to identify the problem and suggest a fix for it. For example, where are you trying to add the handler and what does it look like at the moment? Have you followed the documentation on [control customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize)?

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I do not want to fix the crash/exception. The handler is added per Microsoft's documentation. Other handlers in our app that were added this way work fine. The documentation always point to using Shell, which we won't as we're trying to migrate existing code to Maui, not rewrite our whole navigation for that. I'm simply asking if there is a known way in Maui, using NavigationPage, on iOS, to achieve the above?